# Secure an API using React with CAS (Single Sign On) for frontend and Spring Boot for backend/Rest API Calls

Tags: reactjs, spring, npm, single-sign-on, cas

I'm working on a React frontend app, and believe I have CAS working correctly to secure the frontend using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cas-client

Now I would like to secure my backend, and only allow the app to access the API calls, presumably using JWTs (or some form of token).  All of the guides I'm finding, however, require the use of Spring Security, and passing the username/password to get the JWT.  In this situation I'm using CAS, so I don't have a username/password to pass in.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your ui is decouple from the backend which i think it is based on your description, you can do this with proxy grant ticket, you can look the offical doc about how the proxy works. following are high level how you can do this with front end and backend decoupled:

1. After user entered right user credentials, cas will do 2 things, on ui your response contains a proxyGrantingTicket, and will send a callback to your backend with pgtId and pgtIou(this is proxyGrantingTicket you received on front end).
2. once you have both pgtId and pgtIou, you will use those information to do the authentication from now on.